# Fetch and async await always returninig undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

one of my server calls took nearly 30 seconds to return the data so it's always getting undefined so I am using the async and promise to resolve this issue but getting "undefined". The following is my code piece Thanks in advance

```
   function fetchFunc() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                // console.log(json)
                return json;
            })
    }

    function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(fetchFunc());
        });
    }

    async function asyncFunc() {
        debugger
        console.log("res" + resolveAfter2Seconds())
        let response = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
        console.log("response = " + response);
    }
    asyncFunc();
```

Comment: u need to return the fetch

Comment: `fetchFunc()` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As peeps said earlier in comments when you expect a function to give you a value you should use `return` keyword for it. So, **in this case, you actually returned the `fetch` response but forgot to return `fetch` promise value itself.**

So your code should look like this:

```js
function fetchFunc() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      // console.log(json)
      return json;
    })
}

function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(fetchFunc());
  });
}

async function asyncFunc() {
  debugger
  console.log("res" + resolveAfter2Seconds())
  let response = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log("response = " + response);
}
asyncFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help I didn't notice that